# Eclipse Link @PostRemove unexptected behavior

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an  entity A that has a @OneToMany relation ship With entity B with Cascade.all and OrphanRemoval=true.
when i remove an item form the List in A and call merge The @PostRemove in B is called in All the items of B not just the removed ONE.

Comment: Does it actually delete all Bs or just the one you want?  Is this a bidirectional 1:M that might also have cascade delete settings set on the other side causing A to be deleted as well?

Comment: yes it is bidirectional 1:m and it is just delete the B removed from the list not all the list while calling the PostRemove in the overall list. i haven't said that A is being deleted